# Por que me marca que el índice esta fuera de la matriz? Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

Quiero leer la suma de los cuadrados de un arreglo con un Parallel.foreach pero me marca que el índice esta fuera de la matriz

```
            Parallel.ForEach(numeros, i =>
        {
            int num = (int)Math.Sqrt(numeros[i]);
            if (num * num == numeros[i])
            {
                suma += numeros[i];
            }
          
        });
```

Probé solo imprimiendo con el parallel para ver si me generaba mas números y ver si ese era el error pero me genera la cantidad especificada

```
            Parallel.ForEach(numeros, i =>
        {
            midelPrint("probar", 6);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El parámetro `i` de la lambda que estás declarando dentro del `ForEach` NO ES el índice del arreglo, es el `iésimo` elemento del arreglo. Por eso el error de que *el índice esta fuera de la matriz*. Tu código debería lucir así:

```
Parallel.ForEach(numeros,i => {
    int num = (int) Math.Sqrt(i);
    if (num * num == i)
    {
        suma += i;
    }
});
```

Ahora bien,eso eliminará el error del índice, pero realmente sigues teniendo errores en tu código. La operación de suma como la estás haciendo actualmente, no es atómica, por lo tanto no es `thread safe` ya que múltiples hilos pueden estar escribiendo al  mismo tiempo. Una posible solución es usando [`Interlocked.Add`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=net-6.0):

```
Parallel.ForEach(numeros,i => {
    int num = (int) Math.Sqrt(i);
    if (num * num == i)
    {
        Interlocked.Add(ref suma, i);
    }
});
```

O bien usando un monitor en un bloque [`lock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock):

```
object monitor = new object();
Parallel.ForEach(numeros,i => {
    int num = (int) Math.Sqrt(i);
    if (num * num == i)
    {
        lock (monitor)
        {
           
            suma += i;
        }
    }
});
```